# How to use python to call Huawei Push API to authenticate and send simple messages?

Tags: python, api, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

My Huawei device does not show push notifications. I got the developer account and app created in their portal.
In the app settings, I got the client id and client secret. I am trying to test sandbox using Python but I could not get the server return access token success.
{
"sub_error": 12304,
"error_description": "invalid client_secret",
"error": 1101
}

Why is it invalid client secret? What could be wrong in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we need to use App id and app secret in the http client id and client secret field as python:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com")
payload = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<app id>&client_secret=<app secret>'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
conn.request("POST", "/oauth2/v3/token", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

It is kind of swapped… but this is how to do it correctly, in python